Why my output is not concatinating, and its gives the same line
Just start learning react. When I run my code it’s giving the exact same line and not concatenating the firstname and lastname. It should be AlveraKhan but it gives $ {firstName} $ {lastName}.
This is the output:

function App() {let firstName ="Alvera" let lastName ="Khan"
  return (<div> <h1> { '$ {firstName} $ {lastName}' } </h1> </div>)}

I omitted the inverted comma, but its gives error.

You do not need template literals. React can easily render this as a ReactNode in JSX.

It looks like you're using template literals incorrectly in your React component. Template literals should use backticks () instead of single quotes ('). Also, when embedding JavaScript expressions in JSX, you should use curly braces {}` without the dollar sign and curly braces inside them. Here's the corrected code:
function App() {
  let firstName = "Alvera";
  let lastName = "Khan";
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{`${firstName} ${lastName}`}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

With this corrected code, the output should correctly display "Alvera Khan". Here's a breakdown of what was changed:
Replaced single quotes (') with backticks (`) to properly use template literals.
Removed the dollar sign and curly braces inside the JSX curly braces to embed the JavaScript expression correctly.
